# Removing rows by reference using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, subset, delete-row

I am trying to figure out how to remove a group of rows from a dataset by reference. For example, with this data set:

```
testset <- data.table(date=as.Date(c("2013-07-02","2013-08-03","2013-09-04","2013-10-05","2013-11-06")), 
           yr = c(2013,2013,2013,2013,2013), 
           mo = c(07,08,09,10,11), 
           da = c(02,03,04,05,06), 
           plant = LETTERS[1:5], 
           product = as.factor(letters[26:22]), 
           rating = runif(25))
```

I want to remove all rows where the product is "y". I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: `testset[product != "y"]`?

Comment: [This is on the to-do list](http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2092&group_id=240&atid=978).

Comment: @Arun I can't seem to access the above link (I see a "Permission Denied" message on R-Forge).  Has this feature been implemented?

Comment: @random_forest_fanatic, oops, we have moved to github. Here is the new link: [FR #635](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635). Sorry we have not gotten to it yet.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

you can use either of the following commands -

```
testset_new <- subset(testset,product!="y")
```

or

```
testset_new <- testset[testset$product!="y",]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since it copies the data.table.

Comment: In that case, you overwrite your existing data - testset <- subset(testset,product!="y")

Comment: @RHelp That's not the point. What if you are inside the function and you are expected to modify the data.table given in the arguments? Replacing **is not** modification in place (by reference).